# How to maintain current URL in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

once again I'm lost. I'm gonna start ahead with the issue, because I am not even sure what I really want.

Example:
I have an article view. The URL is: `http://index.php/news/article/3`
This actually runs the `article($id)` function in my `news` controller and gives it the `3` as an argument. The function then fetches the article information and displays it in the view.

On the article page, the user can also log in. Logging in is triggered on pressing
submit button inside my form `form_open('core/login')`...button...`</form>` In the function I log the user in and refresh the current view with some elements changed according to the user being logged. The problem is that the URL is now `http://index.php/core/login`. Obviously I would like it to be the original URL.

Is there any, possibly simple, solution to achieve this? Thank you all for reading and in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult without more code but let me give you my theory / take on this:

Default controller:

1. User is not logged in - show default header, content, footer
2. User presses login, form is shown
3. User is authenticated - yes (continue) no (go back to form)
4. User is redirect('home')'d
5. Your default controller/home controller checks if auth'd: if authorised then show logged in header, content and logged in footer
   or simply pass 'loggedIN' as a $data['loggedIN'] variable to the view - but this breaks the ideology of MVC framework.

More info from you and I can be more specific, or we can talk on IRC.

Adding this code from a controller i'm working on right this minute - I use ion_auth library (you should look it up, it's excellent).

This is my default controller - and as you can see some simple logic loads the different views/states.

```
public function index(){


        if ($this->data['auth_login'] ) {

            /*is already signed in so just present the lobby?*/
            $data['page_title'] = "HN Lobby";
            $data['menuItems'] = nav_anchor_helper_authd();
            $data['myUserID'] = $this->ion_auth->get_user_id();

            $data['lobby_players'] = $this->lobby_model->get_players();

            $this->load->view('template/public/header',$data);
            $this->load->view('player_pages/nav_2',$data);
            $this->load->view('player_pages/lobby',$data);



            $this->load->view('template/scripts/main',$data);/*scraper and other scripts*/
            $this->load->view('template/public/footer',$data);

        } else {

            /*request login*/
            $data['page_title'] = "PLAY HN";
            $data['menuItems'] = nav_anchor_helper();

            $data['auth_rtnurl'] = current_url();
            $data['auth_conturl'] = current_url(); /*for now just come back to same page where lobby should load - perhaps in future a semi gooey login? e.g where was user going - this could be the continue url in this var right here << */

            $data['message_body'] =   $this->session->flashdata('message');


            $this->load->view('template/public/header',$data);
            $this->load->view('template/public/nav_1',$data);
            $this->load->view('public_pages/play',$data);
            $this->load->view('template/public/footer',$data);
        }
    }
```

Here is how I handle the return URL in my login function:
Login/auth controller: (using ion_auth)

```
function login()
    {
        $this->data['title'] = "Login";

        //validate form input
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('identity', 'Identity', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
        {


            if ($this->ion_auth->login($this->input->post('identity'), $this->input->post('password'), $remember))
            {
                //if the login is successful
                //redirect them back to the home page
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());



                $rtnurl = $this->input->post('auth_conturl');
                if(!$rtnurl || $rtnurl == ""){
                    $rtnurl = '/';
                }

                redirect($rtnurl, 'refresh');
            }
```

This is only an extract/segment of the login function - but as you can see i utilise the function 'redirect' from code igniter to push the user back to the return URL posted with the login form (which was set in the view/previous controller using the current_url() function.

Finally my default view file with login form to show you how i am passing the return url:

```
<div>

    <h4>Login</h4>
    <div id="infoMessage" class="errortext"><?php echo $message_body;?></div>


    <?php echo form_open('auth/login', array('class' => 'form col')); ?>

      <p>
        <label for="identity">Email:</label>    <input type="text" name="identity" value="" id="identity">  </p>

      <p>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>    <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password">  </p>

      <p>
        <label for="remember">Remember Me:</label>    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1" id="remember">  </p>


      <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login &raquo;"></p>


    <p>
        <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/auth/forgot_password">Forgot password</a> ?
    </p>



      <input type="hidden" name="auth_rtnurl" value="<?php echo $auth_rtnurl; ?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="auth_conturl" value="<?php echo $auth_conturl; ?>"/>

    <?php echo form_close();?>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm doing `$this->session->set_userdata($user_id);` during the registration. And in my `view` I have `if($this->session->userdata($user_id)){displays content available only to logged in user)else{not logged content}` Very simply said.

Comment: I also store the current view name in the session, that was the only way I figured out how to make it so that the user can log in and out on any page and stay on it.

Comment: It's 1am here. I'm calling it a day. If you want add me on Skype: warriotox or email me at james.belik@gmail.com I'll be back in 8hours. Gl with your project. I hope you'll leave another comment here ;)

Comment: Could you re-phrase your original question, I appreciate it's sometimes difficult to nail down the exact problem, but by trying to work out exactly what you want we might be able to get to an agreeable solution

Comment: When I call login, logout and other functions on a page I don't want them to change the URL.

Comment: So you are looking for a login/logout via AJAX setup? - I simply redirect a user back to where he/she was browsing pre-login as seen in my code above "$data['auth_rtnurl'] = current_url();"

Comment: `current_url();` is that a CodeIgniter function or something you've wrote? Can you post the link to the documentation for it or the code you're using? Also I have tried to do something like when the user logs in on `detail_v` view the login function at the end calls the `detail` function, but my URL is still the name of the 1st function that is triggered..

Comment: Or like, how do you treat the `auth_rtnurl`? What do you do with it inside the view?

Comment: You will need to load the URL helper function (i load mine in the config/autoload file): see more info: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

function current_url is useful as mentioned above.

I will add some more code to my answer to help answer some more of your questions here

Answer (score 0):

To use the current dynamic url as form action, just use -

```
<?= form_open(current_url()); ?>
```